# map method of Python multiprocess Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
def pool_process(f, data, pool_size):
    tp1 = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes=pool_size)
    result = pool.map(f, data)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("Results", result)
    print("Overall Time:", round((time.time()-tp1),2))
    return round((time.time()-tp1),2)

def check_prime(num):
    print(multiprocessing.current_process(), multiprocessing.current_process().pid)
    t1 = time.time()
    res = False
    if num > 0:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                print(num,"is not a prime number")
                print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
                print("Time:", int(time.time()-t1))
                break
        else:
            print(num,"is a prime number")
            print("Time:", time.time()-t1) 
            res = True
    return res

dataRange = range(10000)
pool_process(check_prime, dataRange, 6)
```

I'm trying to test this multiprocessing in python in Jupiter notebook, the program actually started with normal output and just froze there after a few seconds. I thought the code somehow got stuck somewhere, so I used ps -elf | grep PID to check the status of one of the processes after the execution started, I got S almost all the time and sometimes a U which I have no idea what it means. Then if I used ps -elf | grep PID to check the status of the process later, there was no trace of it and the program in the notebook also didn't end. I googled something about this map method and still have no clue what was going on. Appreciate it if anyone could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `Pool.map` method takes as input a function (say, `f`) and an iterable (say, the list `[x, y, z]`) and it applies that function to each item in the iterable, returning a new iterable (in this case, 
`[f(x), f(y), f(z)]`).

The `Pool.map` method differs from the vanilla `map` function in that `Pool.map` uses parallelism, which is why it's a method of the Pool object. (Optionally, you can also specify a "chunksize" parameter to tell Python how you want `Pool.map` to split up the work, so to speak.)

Hope this helps!

Relevant Python doc: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map